# Android TextView text and CompoundDrawable bidi issue

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anyone tell me why doesn't the start drawable of a `TextView` align properly when there is some text in a RTL language with `layoutDirection` set to "`locale`"?

The text is on the right (where it should be) but the image is on the left (even though it is a `startDrawable`)

Note: if the `layoutDirection` is set to "`inherit`" everything works as expected.

Comment: Try drawableRight instead of drawableStart

Comment: The solution works fine when layoutDirection is set to "inherit".
I am just curious why wouldn't locale do the job too. (if the loacle is set to e.g. Hebrew)